# How to return boolean true/false in javascript String match for single alphabetical string?

Tags: javascript, regex

My requirement to return `true` or `false` based on checking whether a string is single word with only Alphabets in it.

I tried following:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = /[a-zA-Z]+/.test("Hello123");
}
</script>
```

But this is returning me `true` instead of expected `false`

Am I using `regexObject.test( String )` in wrong way ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the string starts (`^`), ends (`$`) and contains only letters:

```js
console.log("Hello123", /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test("Hello123"));

console.log("Hello", /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test("Hello"));
```

Comment: Thanks Ori, I got it !!

Answer (score 2):

You need a start symbol `^` and an end symbol `$` as well for checking the whole string.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test("Hello123");
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

You could shorten the regular expression with insensitive flag.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = /^[a-z]+$/i.test("Hello");
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Nina.
I was doubting what `^` and `$` for, so was testing without it.